# Inconsistent result iterating through a dictionary with list inside?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a python script that is passed an argument from user input of server name or an input xlsx file of server name.

The large data structure that is a dictionary with list for each key. the list can have a lot of items per key. The arguments are passed to the function to loop through and i am getting inconsistent result that baffles me.

I've tried various things such as decoupling the code from script to test and testing other suggestions i've searched.

-snippet of dict with lists, that i collect from remote linux server:

```
{'ABC-OS-WIN': ['server1', 'server2', 'SERVER3', 'server4',....., 'server5', 'SERVER6', 'server7', 'SERVER8', 'SERVER9'], 'DEF-OS-ZFS': [], 'EFG-OS-UNX': ['server10', 'server11', 'SERVER12', 'server13',....., 'server14', 'SERVER15', 'server16', 'SERVER17', 'SERVER18']}
```

-Parse data of input from xlsx file that will be used to check against the above data structure. Items in list are Upper case by default

```
server_list = ['SERVER1', 'SERVER2']
```

When i pass that server_list in Uppercase to my function, it searches for the first server and fails finding the server and stops looping. But when i change the server_list names to lower case, it finds the server in my data structure and loops through both items in the list.

-Snippet of code that read input file and build collection of server to check:

```
def main():
#other code here
server_list = []
        if len(infile_dict) == 0:
            print ("No Backup Steps")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            for i in infile_dict:
                if i == "Hostname":
                    for j in infile_dict['Hostname']:
                        server_list.append(j)

        print(server_list)
        for srv in (server_list):
            srv = srv     #when i have this it loops first item in list
            #srv = srv.lower()   #if i uncomment this, then it loops through all
            run_book(srv)
            input("press any key to continue")
```

```
class ClientNotFoundError(Exception):
    """ This exception can be rasied if client is not found in Backup """
    pass
```

```
def run_book(hostname):
    #if exist server, server name will be stored in client_alive
    client_alive = check_marley_hostname(hostname)
    print("clientalive ", client_alive)
    print("...", client_alive)

    if client_alive == None:
        print("...not active client", hostname)
        raise ClientNotFoundError(hostname, "Server not active backup client")

    if not client_alive:
        print("...elif not active client", hostname)
        raise ClientNotFoundError(hostname, "Server not active backup client")

    if client_alive == hostname:
        print("inside clientalive[0]")
        country_location = get_country_code(hostname)
        print("countrylocation", country_location)
        ssh_connect_host = get_nbu_master_server(country_location)
        print("ssh_connect_host" , ssh_connect_host)

        # all_active_policies = get_active_nbu_policies()
        all_active_policies = get_active_nbu_policies(ssh_connect_host)

        all_policies_and_clients = get_active_policies_client(ssh_connect_host, all_active_policies)
        print("clients in policies", all_policies_and_clients)

        active_client = check_host_in_policy(hostname, all_policies_and_clients)
        print("active cleint", active_client)
```

-Example console execution result showing it stops after first server

```
In [1]: run cray.py -I excelDoc.xlsx
excelDoc.xlsx
...Input file passed
..cwd D:\Test\Py
...Pathfile D:\Test\Py\infile\excelDoc.xlsx
['SERVER1', 'SERVER2']
... SERVER1
...Check if server exist in Inventory
 HOSTmon* Command Line Interface
[
  {
    "hostname" : "server1",
    "country" : "us"
  }
]
empty list
clientalive  None
... None
...not active client SERVER1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ClientNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Test\Py\cray.py in <module>
    382
    383 if __name__ == "__main__":
--> 384         main()

D:\Test\Py\cray.py in main()
    378                         srv = srv
    379                         #srv = srv.lower()
--> 380                         run_book(srv)
    381                         input("press any key to continue")
    382

D:\Test\Py\cray.py in run_book(hostname)
    254         if client_alive == None:
    255                 print("...not active client", hostname)
--> 256                 raise ClientNotFoundError(hostname, "Server not active b
ackup client")
    257                 #sys.exit()
    258         if not client_alive:

ClientNotFoundError: ('SERVER1', 'Server not active backup client')
```

From the execution result, i see that it can't find the server because I passed it as upper case. So to get around that i can convert list to lower case and looks like it works. secondly and more important, why does it stop after the first server and not loop through the second? thought the class expection i have would allow for that, or im not understanding correctly. Baffling to me.

Comment: I figured out how to convert the list in the dictionary to lower case as follows: `clients = [client_name.strip().lower() for client_name in clients_cmd.stdout.split('\n') if client_name.strip()]` as looks like its working. will do more tests. Im still interested to understand why it worked on some and failed on others?

Comment: can you add examples of lists that it doesn't work on?

Comment: Hi @Caleb, I update the question with more detail, hopefully it provides more insight